# NUnit keeps tcp connections alive

Tags: c#, tcp, nunit

Simple class using a TcpListener (this is just to present the problem, by no means this class makes any practical sence):

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace NUnitTcp
{
    public class Foo
    {
        TcpListener lst;

        public Foo()
        {
            lst = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9090);
        }

        ~Foo()
        {
            lst.Stop();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            lst.Start();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            lst.Stop();
        }

    }
}
```

A simple application that uses Foo:

```
using System;

namespace NUnitTcp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo f = new Foo();
            f.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

This application runs fine, port is released as soon as the app ends and the app can be run again! Even without the destructor in Foo this would still happen!

A simple NUnit test with Foo:

```
using System;
using NUnitTcp;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace NUnitTcpTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TcpTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void test1()
        {
            Foo f = new Foo();
            f.Start();

            Assert.True(true);
        }
    }
}
```

This test will run just once in the NUnit GUI thingy. Any subsequent execution of that test will throw an exception informing us that the port is in use. The NUnit GUI restart will release the port.
Would you consider this a bug? Seems to me like one...

CORRECTION - the test will randomly throw an exception, for me about 70% of the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The garbage collector is non-deterministic. It only closes promptly in the first example because the process exits. I strongly suggest you implement `IDisposable` instead of using a finalizer, then you can use:

```
using(Foo f = new Foo())
{
    f.Start();
    Assert.True(true);
}
```

safe in the knowledge that it will close promptly.

With something like:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    if(lst != null) lst.Stop();
    lst = null;
}
```

Comment: great! that explains everything! Thanks

Comment: I decided to add a [TearDown] clause to my unit-tests, where I am always stopping the server. I am accepting your answer though as it explains the problem and a correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

Port is in use until your `Foo` instance will not be collected by Garbage Collector. Also thus you have finalizer defined, it will require two garbage collection for finalizer to be called (`Foo` will be moved to finalization queue during first garbage collection, and finalizer will be *possibly* called during second garbage collection). If you want to be sure port will be released, I suggest you to close stop manually `Foo` in `TearDown` method:

```
private Foo _foo;

[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    _foo = new Foo();;
}

[Test]
public void test1()
{
    _foo.Start();
    // Assert 
}

[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
    if (_foo != null)
      _foo.Stop();
}
```

Also it would be nice to implement `IDisposable` on your `Foo` class, because it uses unmanaged resources, which should be released:

```
public class Foo : IDisposable
{
    TcpListener lst;

    public Foo()
    {
        lst = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9090);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        lst.Stop();
    }
}
```